# How to get a list of objects with a 3 table join zend/sql?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have three tables.

- Football_club
- Football_club_player
- Football_club_Title

The last two tables have a many to one
Relationship to the Table Football_club

structure of the tables:

```
Football club
coulmns:

football_club_id
name
...

_______________________________

Football club Player
coulmns:

football_club_player_id
football_club_id
...

________________________

Football_club_Title
coulmns:

Football_club_title_id
football_club_id
...
```

I want to have a list of football clubs. This list have to meet the following ruqueriments:
- There should be NO football clubs in this list that have: exactly one player && zero club title.

Iam working with zend db select. And the List I want to receive should be an array of Model_Football_Clubs.

How to achieve this with zend or in general with sql?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the structure of the tables?

Comment: i added the structure of the tables.

Comment: what about football clubs with no players nor club title ?

Comment: they should be in the list (football club id would be null in this case). only football clubs that have (extactly one Player and at the same time no titles) shouldnt be in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is in general sql.

```
WITH
    more_than_one_player_clubs AS
    (
        SELECT
            plyr.football_club_player_id,
            COUNT(plyr.name)                    AS players,
            COUNT(title.Football_club_title_id) AS titles
        FROM
            Football_club_player plyr
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            Football_club_Title title
        ON
            (
                plyr.football_club_id = title.football_club_id )
        GROUP BY
            plyr.football_club_player_id
    )
SELECT
    clb.football_club_id,
    clb.name,
    plyr.football_club_player_id,
    title.Football_club_title_id
FROM
    Football_club clb
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    more_than_one_player_clubs plyr
ON
    (
        clb.football_club_id = plyr.football_club_id )
WHERE
    (
        plyr.titles > 0
    OR  plyr.player > 1 )
OR (
        plyr.titles = 0
    AND plyr.player = 0 )
```